# How to organize the right way of writing results after processing external program to another directory in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm writing a simple code to automate the processing by external program RNAfold. In this issue I created a directory with folder contains initial data that I send to RNAfold to obtain some results that I want to write in another folder. I faced the problem with redirecting results from RNAfold. What I need to fix?

```
#! /bin/bash

output_dir="$2" # an_level1/an_level2/an_level3

for file in ls "$1"/*.fa; do
    cbf="$(readlink -e "$(file)")"
    cbf_fn="$(basename "$cbf")"                  #*.fa
    filename_WO_ext="${cbf_fn%.*}"               #*  
    RNAfold < "$file" > "${output_dir}/${filename_WO_ext}/.txt";done
```

Comment: Paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @Cyrus, thanks. I fixed bags, but I am not sure that this bash script is a right solution for my problem

Comment: "I faced the problem with redirecting results" - It would help if you were specific as to what the problem is. Don't use `for file in ls "$1"/*.fa` with or without single quotes or backticks. Just do `for file in "$1"/*.fa`. Are you sure you want to execute the files here?: `cbf="$(redline -e "$(file)")"` You should probably remove the inner parentheses: `cbf="$(redline -e "$file")"`. Should `redline` be `readlink`?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, `readlink`, of course.
I want to send this files to external program RNAfold and save results for each file in another folder. What I mean:

I have RF00001.fa in ~\DataFromRfam (~\DataFromRfam\RF00001.fa). I call RNAfold and result save in folder ~\Results  in file RF0001.txt- `RNAfold > ~\DataFromRfam\RF00001.fa << ~\Results\RF0001.txt`

Comment: Well, the code in your question looks alright to me (except for the things I noted in my first comment). But what you posted in your last comment is completely wrong. Unless you're on Windows, the path delimiter should be a slash (`/`) not a backslash (`\\`) and the redirections are backwards.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, I am on Mac OS X, but nevertheless: I should type this: `RNAfold < ~/DataFromRfam/RF00001.fa >> ~/Results/RF0001.txt` instead of `RNAfold > ~/DataFromRfam/RF00001.fa << ~/Results/RF0001.txt`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, this code is a way to automate processing of thousand files, so I am interested in correctness in line `RNAfold < "$file" > "${output_dir}/${filename_WO_ext}/.txt"`

Comment: So you're not having a problem? You just want verification of correctness? That line in your code looks fine to me (except for the issues I pointed out earlier and that I just noticed there's a stray slash just before ".txt" that you probably don't want to be there), but you should test your script on a few of your inout files and if there are no errors and the output is as expected then you should run it on the full data set. Stack Overflow isn't a code review service. You still haven't posted a specific problem for us to help you solve.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, I have a problem, just after running code nothing happend. I mean that no saved results. Moreover, all files delete from initial folder. So I asked here, may be redirectoring is wrong, because no Errors or warnings on terminal windows

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, I was really surprised after vanishing all files, but if it shows any errors or may be warnings I would write it here. Unfortunately, I didn't have this case, so I asked here to get may be more details that I don't know regarding scripts that you can know in the reason of having daily work or something like that